# Cut text off when it has a line break

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am div holding text, I don't want the div to be higher than a certain size or wider than a certain size. I've set the max width and max height on that already. My problem right now is that when the text is so long it gives problems. Is there a way I am able to cut the text off when it has to do a line break?

Edit: I would like two lines of text before the ellipsis start.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you can either have the text appearing on a single line with the ellipsis or have two lines without ellipsis.

Try this for a single line with an ellipsis:

```
.overflow {
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

OR this for two lines without an ellipsis:

```
.overflow {
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    line-height: 1.5em;
    height: 3em;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Here's a [**Sample Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/SiddAjmera/1bc0tq6h/5/) for your ref.

Comment: Thank you so much. This is exactly what I needed!

Comment: One question though, can I make the text flow to two lines before the ellipsis start?

Comment: This may not work in all browsers

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
.overflow {
  line-height: 1.5em;
  height: 3em;
  overflow: hidden; 
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

> This will keep your text max up to 2 lines.

Comment: Can you convert em to px. I don't understand what em is, is it just another way to measure it?

Comment: The ellipsis don't work unless I add 'white-space: nowrap;' but then it is only allowing one line of text.